# SpriteKit + AVAudioPlayer in touchesMoved: kills fps

Tags: sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, frame-rate

In a SpriteKit app, I am playing a click sound when the user moves a block on the screen, but this causes terrible lagging (fps dropping to near zero).

Code:

• `self.audioPlayers` is a strong NSMutableArray which holds currently playing `AVAudioPlayer`s and removes them when the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:` delegate method is called.

• The `blockShouldMove` method compares the touch location to its previous location and only returns YES if the user has moved the cursor enough distance so we only play a maximum of around 8 sounds simultaneously.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *oneTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [oneTouch locationInNode:self];

    if (![self blockShouldMove:location]) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click_01.mp3" ofType:nil];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath] error:nil];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self.audioPlayers addObject:audioPlayer];
}
```

On both simulators and real devices (iOS and tvOS), if I make circles with my finger, the fps drops to almost nothing until well after I have even released my finger.

If I remove the whole `AVAudioPlayer` and use `[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"click_01.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]`, everything works fine. But unfortunately, `SKAction` sound handling is terrible for my purpose because the volume cannot be set.

Is there anything that can be done to make this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an indirect sort of "answer", more a comment but it's too long to write it in that form.

I ran into something like this issue with a SpriteKit game.  I solved it by dropping the `AVAudioPlayer`s and instead using the scene's audio engine.  I connected a bunch of `AVAudioPlayerNode`s to the main mixer node and started them playing (nothing).  Whenever I'd want a sound effect of some sort, I'd grab the next audio player node (round robin fashion, and there were enough of them so that I was sure it would be idle) and schedule a preloaded sound buffer for it.

The point is that for more complicated audio in SpriteKit, you may need to go through the audio engine and build a sound graph that's appropriate for what you want to do.  Multiple `AVAudioPlayer`s existing at once seem to be stepping on each other somehow and causing lag.

However if you didn't try the `SKAudioNode` functionality yet, I'd say do that first.  You should be able to run an action on the audio node to adjust volume.  I didn't go that route since I couldn't get the stereo panning to work the way I wanted with that setup.  If that works for what you want to do, it's probably simpler than setting up your own sound graph.

If you want to see the solution I eventually used, you can look at https://github.com/bg2b/RockRats/blob/master/Asteroids/Sounds.swift